# Move subdirectory and all branches to new git repo

Tags: git, github

I have a git repo (let's say *https://github.com/user/baseproject*) and I want to move the subdirectory **subdir1** to a new git repo, i.e. *https://github.com/user/subdir1**. I could make this with master branch. But I also want to move the content of this subdirectory from other branches to this new github repo.

Is there some way to do it? How can I do this?

Comment: [Dillo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67334764/1256452)'s link has the seeds of a complete answer. I'm not going to write up the whole thing, but the filter-branch method works fine: you just need to create *branch names* locally for each branch, then use `--branches` or `--all` during the filtering to make sure you get all names handled and all commits copied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution to my problem. The steps described https://docs.github.com/en/github/getting-started-with-github/splitting-a-subfolder-out-into-a-new-repository are still valid, but with some minor changes

1. Before calling `git filter-branch`, make a `git checkout BRANCH && git pull` of all branches which should be part of the new git repo.
2. Don't forget to checkout back to master `git checkout master`
3. When calling `git filter`, use `-- --all` instead of a branch name, i.e. `git filter-branch --prune-empty --subdirectory-filter FOLDER-NAME -- --all`
4. At the end, after setting the new remote url, push everything to the new git repo: `git push --all origin`

Answer (score 0):

Splitting a subfolder out into a new repository
You can turn a folder within a Git repository into a brand new repository.

https://docs.github.com/en/github/getting-started-with-github/splitting-a-subfolder-out-into-a-new-repository

Comment: I tried it this way, but everytime when I try it, I see only master branch on github, but my aim to get all branches that were also existing in the *baseproject* github repo.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one potential solution that involves some manual steps:

1. `cd` into the directory containing your local clone of the `baseproject` repository.
2. Add your `https://github.com/user/subdir1` repository as a new remote of `https://github.com/user/baseproject` so that you can push all your commits and branches to the new repository: `git remote add subdir1 git@github.com:user/subdir1.git`
3. Push all your branches and commits to your new `subdir1` repository: `git push subdir1 'refs/tags/*' 'refs/heads/*'`
4. Now, `cd` into your local clone of the `subdir1` repository, run `git pull origin <branchname>` to pull in all changes. Then, `mv` the subdirectory to the top level of the repository and `rm` all the undesired files. Note that you may need to repeat this for each of the branches of the original repository if you want `subdir1` to be the root directory in all branches.
5. If desired, you can now `rm` the `subdir1` directory, and then the remote from your local clone of `baseproject`: `git remote rm subdir1`